# Django TypeError missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'

Tags: python, django, typeerror

Django newbie here. For my first project, I'm following a course that I found online which is a website for finding properties, realtors and stuff.

On the landing page, I have a search form which can be used to find properties based on location, price, etc. However though, on submitting the form it gives me the following error.

```
TypeError at /listings/search
listing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/listings/search?keywords=&city=
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
listing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'
Exception Location: /home/nived/Documents/BTRE_PROJECTF/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 124
Python Executable:  /home/nived/Documents/BTRE_PROJECTF/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['/home/nived/Documents/BTRE_PROJECTF',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/nived/Documents/BTRE_PROJECTF/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

I'm not sure which listing_id is being referred to here.

As of now I haven't added any markup to the search.html file. It just has a simple

```
<h1>Search</h1>
```

I wanted to make sure that the pages are linked properly before I begin adding more content.

Index Page html

```
<section id="showcase">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="home-search p-5">
        <div class="overlay p-5">
          <h1 class="display-4 mb-4">
            Property Searching Just Got So Easy
          </h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae quas, asperiores eveniet vel nostrum magnam
            voluptatum tempore! Consectetur, id commodi!</p>
          <div class="search">
            <form action="{% url 'search' %}">
              <!-- Form Row 1 -->
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <label class="sr-only">Keywords</label>
                  <input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword (Pool, Garage, etc)">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <label class="sr-only">City</label>
                  <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <label class="sr-only">State</label>
                  <select name="state" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">State (All)</option>
                    {%for key,value in state_choices.items%}
                      <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
                    {%endfor%}
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Form Row 2 -->
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <label class="sr-only">Bedrooms</label>
                  <select name="bedrooms" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Bedrooms (All)</option>
                    {%for key,value in bedroom_choices.items%}
                      <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
                    {%endfor%}            
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <select name="price" class="form-control" id="type">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Max Price (Any)</option>
                    {%for key,value in price_choices.items%}
                      <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
                    {%endfor%}
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" type="submit">Submit form</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

urls.py in the listings app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[

    path('', views.index,name='listings'),
    path('<int:listing_id>',views.listing,name='listing'),
    path('search',views.listing,name='search'),

]
```

views.py in the listings app

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from .models import Listing

def index(request):

    listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date') .filter(is_published=True)

    paginator = Paginator(listings,6)
    page=request.GET.get('page')
    paged_listings=paginator.get_page(page)

    context={
        'listings':paged_listings 
    }
    return render(request, 'listings/listings.html',context)

def listing(request,listing_id):

    listing=get_object_or_404(Listing,pk=listing_id)

    context = {
        'listing' : listing
    }
    return render(request,'listings/listing.html',context)

def search(request):   
    return render(request, 'listings/search.html')
```

What seems to be the problem here ? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: 1) Are you sure your urls are namespaced properly? urls.py should have a app_name='listings'... 2) The problem is specifically occuring in listings/search/. Please make sure your search.html is indeed empty as you mentioned. ..3)If you are getting error in template in browser,please analyze the full traceback and give the exact line where error is occuring

Comment: My urls are spaced properly. Both the listings and listing methods work without an issue. Search.html just has search written under h1 tags.

Comment: The problem is specifically occurring in search.html.  If you have code hosted somewhere online (like github), perhaps u can share the link

Comment: @coderDude : Thanks for all the help. Just figured it out, really silly mistake ! I configured my urls incorrectly. It took me to views.listing, but I wanted it to take me to the views.search method. Forgot to change the view method after copy pasting the same line. All's well for now. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Attention that white spaces are really dangerous when you're writing your path.
I had the same issue and I noticed that I used a white space between : and id, when I deleted that white space, problem solved.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='listings'),
path('<int:listing_id>', views.listing, name='listing'),
path('search', views.search, name='search'),
```

]